# How to create a ping based monitoring system for my lan

Tags: java, php, windows, terminal, ping

I want to create a ping based monitoring device in windows. When any packet loss or request time out or reply time is more than a particular value,it will provide an alarm to know that. Is it possible???

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ? written any code to achieve this functionality. ?

Comment: No..its my first attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only that it's possible, there is ample work done already.
I think it is better if you use some of the existing software for that, unless you want to do it on your own from scratch.

I would suggest:

System and Network Monitor  -  http://snm.sourceforge.net/
It constantly records the capacity parameters of any networked device using ping among other things. You can set up e-mail alerts if a number of queries fail.

...Or write your own script (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting)

I hope it helps

Comment: I'm really not an expert on windows shell, but I can show you an analogous  implementation for linux.

Comment: and here it is :)
- write a script 

if ! [ "$(ping -c 1 YOUR_IP)" ]; then
   echo "No ping!" | mail -s "Alert" "YOUR@EMAIL.COM"
fi

which basically checks if there is a ping response from YOUR_IP and if not sends an email to YOUR@EMAIL.COM

Now save it in a script and run a chron job that will execute it every minute.

Now the only thing you need to do if figure out how to do it in windows